# passing data between tableView and another view in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, selecteditem

I want to pass selected row's text to another view's label. But this not work. Not pushing second view. How can I solve this problem?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

SecondViewController  *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
NSUInteger row2 = [indexPath row];
NSLog(@"rowden %i",row2);
denemelik=row2;
NSLog(@"kontrol %i",denemelik);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
detailViewController.stringdir= [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
NSLog(@"hoff %@", [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
NSLog(@"kontrol2 %@",ws2.CustomerName);

[detailViewController release];

}
```

in my secondViewController.m viewDidLoad I set the 'stringdir' to label's text:

```
enyakinfirma.text = stringdir;
```

Comment: Have you checked that detailViewController is valid at the point of creation?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand what do you mean valid creation?

Comment: Also, secondViewController have 3 view. Is that so, not pushing?

Comment: Do you actually have an object after the line.... SecondViewController  *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

Comment: ...or is detailViewController nil

Comment: what is nil detailViewController?

Comment: I edited my question about NSString stringdir. Please check now.

Comment: Whether this tableview is pushed with navigation controller? I mean, is there any `UINavigationController` in the stack?

Comment: actually I put table view into the tabController' s first tab. And I want to pass from there to second tab's view. (secondViewController)But, I add navigationController object to appDelegate class.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to swap this 2 line of codes around

```
detailViewController.stringdir= [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

You should set the value before calling the navigationController. At least that's what i am doing.